# Wrong tag at collision number 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

Hello i am making a 2d game and I have a player that needs to collide with 2 objects. First object gives him more health and has the tag " power up " and works but the second that has the tag " Hurt" it's not working . What I should change in the script ? Here it's the script for " PowerUp" and here it's the script of the player.

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
public class PowerUpDetector : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    // reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Character healthbar;
    [SerializeField] private Character health;
   

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!healthbar) healthbar = GetComponent<Character>();
        
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // or whatever tag your powerups have
        if (!other.CompareTag("PowerUp"))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Registered a collision but with wrong tag: {other.tag}", this);
            return;
        }
        
        var powerup = other.GetComponent<PowerUp>();
        if (!powerup)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Object {other.name} is tagged PowerUp but has no PowerUp component attached", this);
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Found powerup, pick it up!", this);
        powerup.Pickup(healthbar);
        if (!other.CompareTag("Hurt"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                photonView.RPC("Damage", RpcTarget.All);
                
            }

            
        }



    }
    [PunRPC]
    void Damage()
    {
        health -= 20;
    }

}
```

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using Photon;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Character : MonoBehaviourPun,IPunObservable
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float dirX;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 5f, jumpForce = 400f, bulletSpeed = 500f;

    [SerializeField] private float health = 100;
    [SerializeField] private Slider slider;
    [SerializeField] private Gradient gradient;
    [SerializeField] private Image fill;

    Vector3 localScale;
   
    public Transform barrel;
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        localScale = transform.localScale;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            
            
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    public float Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set
        {
            health = value;
            slider.value = health;
            fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(slider.normalizedValue);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEntered2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if( col.gameObject.CompareTag ("Hurt"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                photonView.RPC("Damage", RpcTarget.All);
            }
        }
    }
    [PunRPC]
    void Damage()
    {
        health -= 20;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            if (dirX != 0)
            {
                barrel.up = Vector3.right * Mathf.Sign(dirX);
            }

            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                Jump();

            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
                Fire();
            
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }




    void Jump()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            var firedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
            firedBullet.AddForce(barrel.up * bulletSpeed);
        }
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(health);
        }else if (stream.IsReading)
        {
           health = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
    public void SetMaxHealth(int value)
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            slider.maxValue = value;
            // The property handles the rest anyway
            Health = value;
        }

    }
}
```

I have an error in the "Power Up Detector" at health -= 20 (operator -= can't be applied ) to operands type "Character" and " int" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to use `health.Health`. Your variable `health` refers to the `Character` class. As you want to change the health, you would have to use the property of that class instead. So try:

`health.Health -= 20;`

I would recommend to rename the `health` variable to something else related to the `Character` class though.

Comment: it's still shows me this in the console : Registered a collision but with wrong tag: Hurt
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object, Object)

Comment: what I should do? @kokosbrood.

Comment: @raluca2, if I understand correctly you have two objects that your player should hit. Right now if I look at your code, it will check if it hit the ```PowerUp``` tag. If it is not, it will give the error message and exit your function. A bit of code later, you check if the tag is ```hurt```. That will never be reached (you exit at the ```PowerUp``` check). I would use a switch function for example: Switch on the tag; and then add both cases in there. See [link]http://csharp.net-informations.com/statements/csharp-switch-case.htm[/link] for an example using strings.

Comment: Apologies. Different formatting in this comment box. [C# switch case](http://csharp.net-informations.com/statements/csharp-switch-case.htm). You will have to use the ```.tag``` property directly.